# Setting up PHP and mySQL script to automate Postal Paperwork

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, automation, usps

The US post office requires very specific paperwork for EDDM Bulk Mailings.

My boss and I are trying to find a way to automate hours upon hours of work into a minute of work.

Basicly all i want to do is enter the zip code, route number, and mail pieces.

The key thing here is mail pieces if you have 689 mail pieces you would have 7 forms each saying 100 mail pieces and the last form saying 89.

Now i know how i would call all this info from mysql my problem is how to dictate the mail pieces and then create a pdf out of it for every page.

Sorry if this is a vague post but im confused as to how to word it better.

Comment: to vague to broad, break it down , ask a specific code related question

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is your question? Is it regarding the mail pieces? Check this example:

```
<?
  $pieces = 689;
  $totalForms = ceil($pieces/100);
  $piecesOnLastForm = $pieces % 100;

  echo "You have total of ".$pieces." pieces, and that takes ".$totalForms." forms with   ".$piecesOnLastForm." pieces on the last form";

?>
```

Does that get you anywhere?

Comment: hmm you might of made my day. let me see how i can work this.

Answer (score 0):

Just shooting from the hip here because there's not all that much info in the question

1) Pull all data from the database; you should get an array of rows, essentially.

2) array_chunk the resulting rows into chunks of 100 (the last array will only have the 89 elements in it)

3) loop through the chunked array results (each line) and write all the necessary data per line to your PDF.

**Very simplified example:**

```
$input = array(
    'a'=>array("a zip","a route","a address"),
    'b'=>array("b zip","b route","b address"),
    'c'=>array("c zip","c route","c address"),
    'd'=>array("d zip","d route","d address"),
    'e'=>array("e zip","e route","e address"),
    'f'=>array("f zip","f route","f address"),
    'g'=>array("g zip","g route","g address"));
$array_of_arrays = array_chunk($input, 2);

foreach($array_of_arrays as $index=>$mailer) {
    //do things to put into PDF
    foreach($mailer as $idx=>$data) {
        echo "ZIP: ".$data[0]." ROUTE: ".$data[1]." ADDR: ".$data[2]."<br/>";
        if($idx == (end($data)+1)) {
            echo "Moving to next page<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**
ZIP: a zip ROUTE: a route ADDR: a address

ZIP: b zip ROUTE: b route ADDR: b address

Moving to next page

ZIP: c zip ROUTE: c route ADDR: c address

ZIP: d zip ROUTE: d route ADDR: d address

Moving to next page

ZIP: e zip ROUTE: e route ADDR: e address

ZIP: f zip ROUTE: f route ADDR: f address

Moving to next page

ZIP: g zip ROUTE: g route ADDR: g address